# A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, concatenation

I am new to deep learning and coding.

I am trying to concatenate the categorical embedding layer with numeric features to fit into the model for multi-class classification. However, even I tried to [Reshape](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2507) the input, the layers cannot be concatenated. Any help is high appreciated.

Here is my audio input:

```
# fill in the 31 features grabbed from the original data set
audio_input = Input(shape=(31,), name='audio_features')
audio_input = Reshape((1,31))(audio_input)
```

Here is my embedded layer, [reference1](https://www.kaggle.com/colinmorris/embedding-layers), [reference2](https://github.com/knathanieltucker/deep-learning-building-blocks/blob/master/notebooks/Categorical%20Data.ipynb):

```
time_signature_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='time_signature')
time_signature_embedded = Embedding(train.time_signature.max()+1, min(600, round(1.6 * time_signature_size**0.56)), input_length=1, name='time_signature_embedded')(time_signature_input)
```

When I tried to concatenate:

```
concatenated = Concatenate()([cats,audio_input])
out = layers.Flatten()(concatenated)
```

I got the error:

```
A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [((None, 1, 6),(None, 1, 31)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
audio_input = Input(shape=(31,), name='audio_features')
time_signature_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='time_signature')

nb_unique_classes = train.time_signature.max()+1
embedding_size = min(600, round(1.6 * time_signature_size**0.56))
    
time_signature_embedded = Embedding(nb_unique_classes , embedding_size , input_length=1, name='time_signature_embedded')(time_signature_input)
time_signature_embedded = Reshape(target_shape=(embedding_size,))(time_signature_embedded)  

model_layers = concatenate([time_signature_embedded] + [audio_input])
```